# Proper way to for multiple programmers to work on the same project at the same time?

Tags: git, bash, github, project

I've done some research and it doesn't seem obvious of what is of the conventions for when multiple programmers have an idea and want to code something together. The initial answer would be "create a github repo" and then periodically push changes to the repo but honestly that doesn't answer any of the concerns that could come up:

- Whose Github account creates the repo? Is there any way to create the repo as a 'shared' repo? Who is the person that gets control? This seems somewhat important as he/she would control everything incase things went south.
- How would I push changes to a repo like that if another one of the project members created it? I've only pushed changes to my own projects by doing 'git push origin master' when the file is on my own hard disk. Anything outside of that and I have absolutely no idea how to push changes.
- Let's say I'm working on a class and, unbeknownst to me, one of my project partners submits a huge amount of work on a class that I thought no one had started or worked on yet. If the answer to this bullet point is "plan better with your team", then I would argue that a tool where I could see this happening in real time would solve this problem completely.
- Every single time I want to work more on the project, do I need to download the zipped file from Github (Perhaps there's a way to do this easily from Git Bash)? That would be a colossal pain. Right now I use dropbox which updates my projects to all my devices automatically, but for multiple people that would not work. It would be nice for everything to sync automatically.

  Forgive me if this is either A. not the right place to ask or B. too basic of a question for Stack Overflow but I've gotten no help from researching from search engine queries. My knowledge of Github and shell terminals are extremely basic so in answers if you could be very descriptive, I would be very appreciative.

Thank you.

Comment: This will help: https://try.github.io

Comment: Did you get the information you needed? Are there any more open questions on this topic? :)

Answer (score 2):

> Whose Github account creates the repo? Who is the person that gets control? This seems somewhat important as he/she would control everything incase things went south.

The person, that is the representative of the group should create and hold the repository. If you want to create some neutrality, you could all agree on an uninvolved person of your trust that maintains control over the main github account. There is also an option for [organisation accounts](https://help.github.com/articles/what-s-the-difference-between-user-and-organization-accounts/) - but I haven't looked deeper into that.

> Is there any way to create the repo as a 'shared' repo?

**YES there is.** You can add collaborators to your project, as it is described in [this official article](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/). To have a short introduction to what a collaborator is, see [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/types-of-collaborative-development-models/).

> How would I push changes to a repo like that if another one of the project members created it? I've only pushed changes to my own projects by doing 'git push origin master' when the file is on my own hard disk. Anything outside of that and I have absolutely no idea how to push changes.

This is no problem and described [in](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/) [many](http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2) [artices](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-remote). You can `push` and `pull` to and from remote repositories. But besides how you techncally do it, it is important for your to agree on a commit strategy. Read [this](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-remote) article. It presents you with different strategies you could use and adapt to your needs. The best strategy depends on your team, what your preferences are and how many people work together.

> Let's say I'm working on a class and, unbeknownst to me, one of my project partners submits a huge amount of work on a class that I thought no one had started or worked on yet. If the answer to this bullet point is "plan better with your team", then I would argue that a tool where I could see this happening in real time would solve this problem completely.

You can see changes made to the repository, as soon as they are pushed to the master. But communication is a *really* important thing in software development (and any other group activity by the way). So you should not only rely on a version control system. There are various tools to support communication and organisation of code development, such as [Jira](https://de.atlassian.com/software/jira) and [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/). The later being a tool to notify of changes in the remote code in real time. Also always keep personal contact, at least via some form of skype or telephone conference.
To prevent accidental damage to the codebase, github provides [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/), where a developer can ask the rest of the devs to review and pull his changes to the main codebase.

> Every single time I want to work more on the project, do I need to download the zipped file from Github (Perhaps there's a way to do this easily from Git Bash)? That would be a colossal pain. Right now I use dropbox which updates my projects to all my devices automatically, but for multiple people that would not work. It would be nice for everything to sync automatically.

**NO!** You dont. You perform a `git pull` that will pull all changes made to the remote repository to the local codebase on your computer. Have a look on how to do this [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull).

> Forgive me if this is either A. not the right place to ask or B. too basic of a question for Stack Overflow but I've gotten no help from researching from search engine queries. My knowledge of Github and shell terminals are extremely basic so in answers if you could be very descriptive, I would be very appreciative.

I hope this provides you with a good starting point. Git and github are marvelous tools for collaborative development and there is a vast amount of tools, support and community that makes it even easier.
Feel free to ask any more questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Whose Github account creates the repo?

Github has Organization accounts have Team-based access permissions

> one of my project partners submits a huge amount of work on a class
>   that I thought no one had started

You can create branches and use pull requests to work around this

> do I need to download the zipped file from Github

Git filters out the unchanged files and even you can select from this the ones to be checked in.